# NodeJS Express api check for "data" in the curl request

Tags: node.js

Im kind of new to this, im trying to reply only if the curl is post and it has "--data "Hi!"

```
curl -X POST --data 'Hi!' localhost:3000
```

```
app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    try {
         //add check to see that it has the string "Hi!"
if (req.body == "Hi!"){
res.send("GOOD")
}


           res.send("Not good")


    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
})
```

but this doesnt work, id be happy for some help

Comment: So have you done any basic debugging? What _is_ req.body?

Comment: yeah, req.body = { 'Hi!': '' }

Comment: Then is it unclear why that `!== "Hi!"`?

Comment: req.body == "{ 'Hi!': '' }" also doesnt work

Comment: That's comparing an object to a string, so no they're not equal. Even comparing the object to an object wouldn't work, because they're compared by reference. Fundamentally I doubt you want that body to be interpreted as form data.

Comment: so i need to convert req.body to string before this?